# Word for describing ideas/questions that stimulate thought

Tags: word-choice

Is there an specific word that could describe ideas/questions that could stimulate thoughts?

For instance, if someone asks a question:

> 1). If all the nations in the world are in debt, where did all the money go?

This question seems easy to answer on its face, but in giving the easy answer other questions can carry us into deeper issues of government and finance. How would you describe the characteristic of this question that stimulates thought?

Is there a specific adjective for this or are there just compound/hyphenated adjectives?

Note:

The original post provided the example question:

> Why is *red* red?

Comment: Have you tried researching this using a thesaurus? If you type "'thought-provoking', synonyms" into Google, you will get a dozen suggestions - *arresting, enthralling, spellbinding etc*

Comment: Food for thought?

Comment: preoccupation, may be.

Answer (score 2):

My best suggestion would be **generative** : *having the power or function of generating, originating, producing, or reproducing*.

Other words that come to mind are **provocative** (especially if controversial), **engaging** (giving rise to debate or argument), **emotive** or **affective** (if arousing feelings), **seminal** (if referring to highly influential ideas in the past).

Comment: Yeah, "provocative" is pretty good (though it has some meanings which might lead one astray).  I wouldn't call the OP's sample sentence "engaging" (unless you're a paint dealer).

Answer (score 1):

> Word for describing ideas/questions that [truly] stimulate thought

***[Fascinating](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fascinating)*** is the word I would choose:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Extremely interesting:
>
> from the VERB *[fascinate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fascinate)*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.0 Attract the strong attention and interest of (someone):
>
> 1.1 archaic (Especially of a snake) deprive (prey) of the ability to resist or escape by the power of a gaze:

A question that compels thoughtful research and consideration is *fascinating*, but I would not put the question *Why is "red" red?* in that category. *Why do we **call** red things red?* would be a step closer to *fascinating* but would still fall short in my mind. Here is a *fascinating* question:

> If people only use 10-20% of their brains, what is the other 80-90%
>   for?

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fascinate&allowed_in_frame=0) of this word is *fascinating* and particularly relevant to your question:

> 1590s, "*bewitch*, *enchant*," from Middle French *fasciner* (14c.),
>
> from Latin *fascinatus*, past participle of *fascinare* "*bewitch*, *enchant*,
>   *fascinate*,"
>
> from *fascinus* "a *charm*, *enchantment*, *spell*, *witchcraft*," which is of
>   uncertain origin.
>
> Earliest used of witches and of serpents, who were said to be able to
>   cast a spell by a look that rendered one unable to move or resist.
>
> **Sense of "*delight*, *attract* and *hold* the *attention* of" is first
>   recorded 1815.**
>
> To *fascinate* is to bring under a spell, as by the power of the eye; to
>   enchant and to charm are to bring under a spell by some more subtle
>   and mysterious power. [Century Dictionary]
>
> Possibly from Greek *baskanos* "slander, envy, malice," later
>   "witchcraft, sorcerery," with form influenced by Latin *fari* "speak"
>   (see *fame* (n.)), but others say the resemblance of the Latin and Greek
>   words is accidental. The Greek word might be from a Thracian
>   equivalent of Greek *phaskein* "to say;" compare enchant, and German
>   *besprechen* "*to charm*," from *sprechen* "*to speak*."
>
> Watkins suggests the Latin word is perhaps from PIE *bhasko- "band,
>   bundle" via a connecting sense of "amulet in the form of a phallus"
>   (compare Latin fascinum "human penis; artificial phallus; dildo").
>   Related: Fascinated; fascinating.
>
> If [*baskanos*] and *fascinum* are indeed related, they would point to a
>   meaning '*curse*, *spell*' in a loanword from an unknown third language.
>   [de Vaan]

Comment: For "Why is 'red' red?"??

Comment: No, @HotLicks, for ideas/questions that stimulate thoughts. I mentioned in my answer that I thought the example was much less than fascinating :-)

Comment: Reminds me of an old story, but it won't fit in 600 letters.  But ... FANTASTIC!  ;)

Comment: Work up a question that rationalizes telling the story. I am a sucker for a good story.

Comment: I didn't say it was GOOD story.

Comment: LOL! You said ***old*** story. I figure a story has to be good to get old.

Comment: I'm old and I haven't been good (though certainly not as bad as I would have liked).

Answer (score 1):

I would use **evocative**.

> **evocative** (adjective) 
>   bringing strong images or feelings to mind.

For example: *evocative discussion* or *evocative lyrics*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Krzywinski's suggestion of "provocative", you can use the compound word "thought-provoking".

> Thought-provoking: causing people to think seriously about something. *Merriam Webster*

The compound word may be preferred in some context if you want to disambiguate the sense that "provocative" questions arouse emotions, such as anger and laughter, in addition to thoughts.

Alternatively, we may say your example questions are "illuminating" or "revealing". We stress that your questions throw lights on some deep  obscure facts of the world, rather than that they engage the readers in a meaningful way.

> Illuminating: providing insight, clarity, or understanding. *Merriam Webster*

Answer (score 0):

I'm no linguist, but I thought I would contribute since these weren't yet among the given answers:

**Eliciting**

**Catalytic**

**Subversive**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).